# Keras Custom Lambda Layer to Wrap Preprocessing Functions tf.placeholder() runtime error

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, tensorflow, keras

I have written a Keras lambda layer meant to wrap a custom preprocessing function that employs pandas dataframe functionality. It is meant to take a numpy array of input data which is wrapped in a dataframe and passed through the custom function.

Consider the following function, **prepare_data()**, which takes in the raw data input:

```
def prepare_data(df):
    df = df[['userId', 'dataDate','x1', 'x2','x3', 'x4', 'x5','x6', 'x7', 'x8','x9','x10','x11']]
    df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df["dataDate"])
    df.sort_values(by=['userId', 'date'], inplace=True, ascending=True)
    df.rename(columns={'x11': 'x12'}, inplace=True)
    df.drop(['dataDate', 'date'], axis=1, inplace=True)
    df['x6'].fillna(method='ffill', inplace=True)
    df['x7'].fillna(0, inplace=True)
    df['x8'].fillna(0, inplace=True)
    df['x9'].fillna(0, inplace=True)
    df['x10'].fillna(0, inplace=True)
    return df
```

I have accounted for keras layers dealing solely with tensors by returning a result that is converted from a pd dataframe to numpy and then converted to tensor using **tf.numpy_function** and have also instantiated **tf.enable_eager_execution()** at the start of my program to support numpy operations in adjacency with Keras.

When I execute the model, I encounter **RuntimeError: tf.placeholder() is not compatible with eager execution.** when I have not used **tf.placeholder** anywhere. Any help to get past this vague step would be much appreciated.

```
def preprocessing(x):
  prepared_data = prepare_data(pd.DataFrame(data=x, index=new_raw_data.index, columns=new_raw_data.columns))
  return prepared_data.values

def preprocessing_tf(x):
  return tf.numpy_function(func=preprocessing, inp=[x], Tout=tf.Tensor)

def create_model():
  model = Sequential()
  model.add(Lambda(preprocessing_tf, input_shape=new_raw_data.shape, output_shape=processed_data.shape))
  return model


model = create_model()
model.compile(optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.summary
```

Comment: Please add your `prepare_data` function

Comment: I have edited the post to include the `prepare_data()` function